# Mask Data Based on Opportunity Team

Tags: security, data

I am wondering the approach to take on this.. The requirement is to have a certain opportunity type where the data is masked to everyone except the members of the opportunity team...

We are thinking about sharing rules and removing visibility.. but before going there wanted to see if there was a way to mask the data based on user being in the opportunity team or not

Comment: Masked... as in, actually masked with *****?

Or will simple visibility suffice?

Comment: and 'masking' applies to list views and reports as well?  I think an OWD model of private with sharing rules sounds like the best path forward

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the way we are heading, but I was checking all the possible alternatives.. Thanks for the feedback